# Vue3/Vite: module has been externalized

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm trying to use `crypto` to hash strings in a Vue 3 app.

```js
async function hash (token) {
    const data = new TextEncoder().encode(token)
    const byteHash = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data)
    //                            ^ the below error is thrown here

    const arrayHash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(byteHash))
    const hexHash = arrayHash.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('').toLocaleUpperCase()

    return hexHash
}
```

From my understanding, `crypto` is available in the browser nowadays, so it needs no `browserify` replacement.

Nevertheless, I'm getting the following error in my browser console:

```js
Error: Module "crypto" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "crypto.subtle" in client code.
```

I interpret this as "Vite is configured to externalize the `crypto` module in the build process". But I can see no such setting in my `vite.config.js`:

```js
// Plugins:
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

// Utilies:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true
    })
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.mjs', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue']
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000
  },
  test: {
    setupFiles: ['../vuetify.config.js'],
    deps: {
      inline: ['vuetify']
    },
    globals: true
  }
})
```

Are there any "baked in" Vite default settings, that could cause this? Is this configured somewere else? How can I fix this issue and use the `crypto` module in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that NodeJS and the Browser **both** have a module called `crypto` that implements the **webcrypto** standard. Those modules are compatible, but need to be accessed differently. In NodeJS it can be used directly but in the browser it is provided by the `window` context that does not exist in NodeJS.

You don't see the difference if you are working directly in the browser, as `window` is the default context, but Vite is working in the NodeJS context, so it (correctly) decides that this module is not available as `crypto` in the browser and thus throws the error. It does not know/care that this module exists in the browser as well but as `window.crypto`.

Maybe this can be configured in `vite.config.js` somehow, but I am not very familiar with it.

I came up with the following solution instead, which works in both environments:

```js
function getCrypto() {
  try {
    return window.crypto;
  } catch {
    return crypto;
  }
}
```

```js
async function hash(token) {
  const compatibleCrypto = getCrypto();

  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(token);
  const byteHash = await compatibleCrypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);

  const arrayHash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(byteHash));
  const hexHash = arrayHash
    .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('')
    .toLocaleUpperCase();

  return hexHash;
}
```

This function works in both environments now.

Comment: What is `comp`?

Comment: @mikemaccana "compatibility" I guess

Comment: It's just a variable name, but it stands for `compatibleCrypto`. I changed it.